# Error Control mechanism at different layers in OSI model

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, network-protocols

I was reading up a bit on networking and I realized that there was error control and subsequent redelivery mechanisms at every layer. At Layer 1 we have CSMA/CD or CSMA/CA depending on ethernet or wireless. At Layer 2 we have Sliding window ARQ. At Layer 3, considering IP does not have any redelivery mechanism. Assuming the application uses TCP, there is sequencing and redelivery there as well. My question is, when transmitting a TCP packet from 1 host to another, do all the error control and redelivery mechanisms come into the picture in their respective layer?

Comment: Of course, that's what they're for. But I'd warn you against applying the OSI model to TCP/IP. It doesn't map. TCP has its own model, which incidentally predates OSI.

Comment: Thanks EJP for the response! Usually there will be a disparity between the theoretical and the practical knowledge of how things are implemented. This question was to clear out if these technologies are still used or if we have any advances.